# Data transfer with discord bot to sqlite db

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

I have made a bot and connected it to discord and that works fine.
From my bot.js file, it will display messages fine within discord.

Example:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '!intro') {
    msg.reply('\n Hi, this is the intro');
  }
});
```

I've now created a SQLite Database with 2 tables and a column in each table and have entered some data into them.

Table 1 called System with the column called SysName
Table 2 called Players with the column called PlayerName

Running commands on my laptop using the sqlitestudiocli.exe.
It all works fine and I can add, update, amend, delete and display within that.

Examples:

```
SELECT * FROM System; displays all the systems
SELECT PlayerName FROM Players WHERE PlayerName LIKE '%S%'; displays all the Players beginning with S
INSERT INTO SYSTEM (SysName) VALUES('Dobbys Sock'); to insert a system called Dobbys sock 
(Why that? I think too much coffee!)
DELETE FROM SYSTEM WHERE SysName=('Dobbys Sock');
```

Etc Etc...

I've connected my database to Discord using the following code:

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./mydb', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the mydb database.');
});
```

That displays fine and says it's connected.

The issue I have is trying to read and write to the database from within Discord.
I'm not sure how to do this and after looking at tutorials, I'm even more confused!

The end goal is to type a command into Discord to add, amend and display the info from these tables.
Can someone please help me?

Thank you x

Comment: You are not accessing SQLite from discord. You are accessing it from Node.js. Maybe you've been looking for tutorials with the wrong keywords? There are plenty examples for working with SQLite from Node.js. For example here https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't get a notification on your reply.
I have looked through and it still doesn't see the tables